# Edittext - How do I only allow one dot to be added?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

This is my edittext

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etWaardeVan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="0123456789."
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
```

How do I programmatically allow for only one dot to be input.

Comment: Does your edittext accept only numbers and dots or accepts characters aswell?

Comment: override afterTextChanged method, check if your edittext already contains "." then replace all dots with whitespace maybe

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Set EditText Digits Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300490/set-edittext-digits-programmatically)

```
etWarDevan.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
```

Comment: you still can insert more than one dot symbol

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the last entered character if its a dot and there has been one before.

```
EditText field = view.findViewById(R.id.etWaardeVan);
field.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String str = editable.toString();
                String strold = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);
                String lastchar = str.substring(str.length() - 1);
                if(strold.contains(".") && lastchar.equals(".")) field.setText(str);
            }
        });
```

Hint: this only works if the user doesn't jump back and enters the dot in the middle of the string. You may want to disable cursor movement. (Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787157/9145163) or using `android:cursorVisible`)

Alternatively (if the input always contains a dot) you can just create two EditTexts without a dot allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, and it works:

```
dot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //only show one dot if user put more than one dot
            if(input.contains(".")){
             //then save what it has
                input = textView.getText().toString();
            }else {
            //concat the input value
                input=input+".";
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, **EditText** is derived from **TextView** which has a

```
void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)
```

method. **TextWatcher** has callbacks, like

```
abstract void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

that you can implement in order to filter the new text to only contain period.

Regex:  `(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )`

Example

```
 et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Do something here with regex pattern
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In AfterTextChangeListener add Regex

val isSingleDot = Regex("\.").findAll("sample.sample").count() <= 1

Answer (score -2):

Set inputType attribute in EditText/TextInputEditText as `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

Comment: you still can insert more than one dot symbol